# Passing django url with tag to d3 js

Tags: django, d3.js

I am trying to pass a url to `d3.json` and the url contains a variable.

The url looks like this: `url(r'my/url/(?P<tag>[0-9]{2})', some_view, name='my_url')`. The url is to a view, which returns a json file.

The html template containing the piece of code looks like this:

```
d3.json("{% url 'my_url' tag %}", function(d){
     //do some stuff

});
```

Sadly, I am getting a **NoReverseMatch** error. How should I pass the tag to `d3.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, somebody better with Django gives you a more elegant answer - but here's something that should work.

```
d3.json("{% url "my_url" %}?tag={{tag}}", function(d) ...
```

then, I'm not sure if this is why your url isn't working, but you may not need to define the get parameters in your urls.py, but instead in the views.py or viewsets.py file where some_view is defined grab the GET parameters with:

```
def some_view(requests):
    ...
    tag = request.GET.get("tag", 0)
```

I say this because there are two possible problems you are facing.  One is how you define or pass the tag from the html (d3(url)) and the other is on the urls.py side.  I hope this helps.